# Datepicker “fengyuanchen/datepicker” outputting only 'Day' into value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using [Datepicker](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker/blob/master/README.md#methods) to select a date from an input field and return it back into the value before submitting a form. The problem is, when using `.getDate` it's returning only the first day. I need the value to output as `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Any help would be great!

```js
jQuery('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  pick: function(e) {
    var date = e.date.getDate();
    jQuery(this).attr('value', date)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<input id="leftBound" data-date-format="yyyy.mm.dd" data-toggle="datepicker" class="leftBound form-control" type="input" name="left_bound" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker/blob/master/README.md#methods):

```
var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate', true);
```

```js
jQuery('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    pick: function(e) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate', true);
        jQuery(this).attr('value', date)
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/js/datepicker.js"></script>


<input id="leftBound" data-date-format="yyyy.mm.dd" data-toggle="datepicker" class="leftBound form-control" type="input" name="left_bound" value="" />
```